# pool.request().query(sqlQuery) RowsAffected

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I need some insight on how the `pool.request().query(sqlQuery)` works.

I have the code working fine and all, but I need to learn what all I can do with the result of the query.

My current code within a function:

```
const result = await pool.request().query(sqlQuery);
return result;
```

In this code, when I run the debugger and inspect the value of result, I see

```
output:Object {}
recordset:Array(1) [Object]
recordsets:Array(1) [Array(1)]
rowsAffected:Array(0) []
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
```

So I was assuming that the I can use these. I went ahead and used

```
  const result = await pool.request().query(sqlQuery);
      logger.info(" rows affected "+ rowsAffected.Array(0));
// The above is where I am not sure how I can get the rows affected.
     return result;
```

I don't seem to be winning here, as the console log says

> rows affected undefined.

I obviously don't know my ways here and there is probably something I am missing. I checked the google but all the suggestions are resulting in undefined.

I need the rowsAffected information to pass the right message beck to the response. How do I get the rowsAffected value

What would I be missing?

Comment: First of all, it looks like you have a syntax error in logger. Use the following command in order to log the info `logger.info("rows affected "+ result.rowsAffected);`. However, keep in mind, that `rowsAffected` will have values only if you have used mutation queries (e.g. insert, update, delete)

Comment: Thanks Yegor, that us what I had actually used in the code. But made a mistake in posting the code. I have corrected the post now. The logger does not print anything for the result.rowsAffected . I was hoping I could get a 0 or more counts here?

Comment: In order to get a count of affected rows you have to use `result.rowsAffected.length`. To be honest, I've never seen such syntax in JS as you used `rowsAffected.Array(0)`. Simple Node JS script with the same syntax throws an error: `a = []; a.Array(0); Thrown: TypeError: a.Array is not a function`

Comment: thanks Yegor, I am new and I might have copied from some online resource.

Answer (score 0):

> rowsAffected:Array(0) []

means that `result` has a property named `rowsAffected` and it's type is an Array. This array happens to have 0 elements.

Change your logger statement to

```
logger.info(" rows affected "+ result.rowsAffected[0]);
```

This is assuming that `sqlQuery` is actually adding or updating records. The fact that you have a 0-element array implies you are not updating any records in this call.

Comment: logger.info(' rows affected '+ result.rowsAffected[0]); prints 
  rows affected undefined

Comment: That's the assumption I wrote about in my answer. What kind of query are you executing?